# Really, really big UIScrollViews

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I'm trying to make a level-of-detail line chart, where the user can zoom in/out horizontally by using two fingers, and grow the contentSize attribute of the the UIScrollView field.  They can also scroll horizontally to shift left or right and see more of the chart (check any stock on Google Finance charts to get an idea of what I'm talking about).  Potentially, the scroll view could grow to up to 100x its original size, as the user is zooming in.

My questions are:
- Has anyone had any experience with UIScrollViews that have such large contentSize restrictions?  Will it work?
- The view for the scroll view could potentially be really huge, since the user is zooming in.  How is this handled in memory?
- Just a thought, but would it be possible to use UITableViewCells, oriented to scroll horizontally, to page in/out the data?

This is kind of an open ended question right now - I'm still brainstorming myself.  If anyone has any ideas or has implemented such a thing before, please respond with your experience.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you come up with any idea? I'm trying to do the same using CATiledLayer or UIView's recycling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have something similar, although probably not to the size your talking about.  The UIScrollView isn't a problem.  The problem is that if you're drawing UIViews on it (rather than drawing lines yourself) UIViews that are well, well off the screen continue to exist in memory.  If you're actually drawing the lines by creating your own UIView and responding to drawRect, it's fine.

Assuming that you're a reasonably experienced programmer, getting a big scroll view working that draws pars of the chart is only a days work, so my recommendation would be to create a prototype for it, and run the prototype under the object allocations tool and see if that indicates any problems.

Sorry for the vagueness of my answer; it's a brainstorming question

Answer (score 1):

This is quite an old topic, but still I want to share some my experiences.
Using such a large UIView (100x than its origin size) in UIScrollView could cause Memory Warning. You should avoid render the entire UIView at once.
A better way to implement this is to render the only area which you can see and the area just around it. So, UIViewScroll can scroll within this area smoothly. But what if user scrolled out of the area that has been rendered? Use delegate to get notified when user scroll out of the pre-rendered area and try to render the new area which is going to be showed.
The basic idea under this implementation is to use 9 UIViews (or more) to tile a bigger area, when user scrolled (or moved) from old position to new position. Just move some UIViews to new place to make sure that one of UIView is the main view which you can see mostly, and other 8 UIViews are just around it.
Hope it is useful.

Comment: Here is a very good example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079225/how-to-implement-uiscrollview-with-1000-subviews

Answer (score 0):

But still, this approach (in the example above) is not good enough in some cases. Cause we only rendered a limited area in the UIScrollView.

User can use different gestures in UIScrollView: drag or fling. With drag, the pre-rendered 8 small UIViews is enough for covering the scrolling area in most of the case. But with flinging, UIScrollView could scroll over a very large area when user made a quick movement, and this area is totally blank (cause we didn't render it) while scrolling. Even we can display the right content after the UIScrollView stops scrolling, the blank during scrolling isn't very UI friendly to user.

For some apps, this is Ok, for example Google map. Since the data couldn't be downloaded immediately. Waiting before downloading is reasonable.

But if the data is local, we should eliminate this blank area as possible as we can. So, pre-render the area that is going to be scrolled is crucial. Unlike UITableView, UIScrollView doesn't have the ability to tell us which cell is going to be displayed and which cell is going to be recycled. So, we have to do it ourselves. Method [UIScrollViewDelegate scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:] will be called when UIScrollView starts to decelerating (actually, scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating is the method been called before decelerating, but in this method we don't know the information about what content will be displayed or scrolled). So based on the UIScrollView.contentOffset.x and parameter targetContentOffset, we can know exactly where the UIScrollView starts and where the UIScrollView will stop, then pre-render this area to makes the scrolling more smoothly.